# Mvc asp.net authentication with users from webapi

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have this situation:

1. I have a MVC4 ASP.NET website on first server.
2. There is WebAPI server that connects to Oracle server.
3. Users of application are stored in Oracle db.

How should I start to customize Web application?
As I already read I suppose to use "Forms" authentication mode.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Home/LogIn" timeout="2880"/>
</authentication>
```

I saw that there is

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(person.UserName, false);
```

to log on. There is

```
FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(...)
```

method that authenticates user.

I persume, I should override somehow Authenticate(...) method. In this implementation method would ask WebAPIServer\api is user and password valid.

Should I use something like CustomUser authentication? Or mybe there is some other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options -

### Option 1

You do not need `FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(...)`, because you will be validating user via Web API.

However, you still need to use `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie`

For example,

```
// Validate user via Web API
// ...
if (User is authenticated) {
   FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(person.UserName, false);
}
```

### Option 2

Implement [Custom Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms366730%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). It takes a little longer to implement than option 1, but **Provider Model** makes the code a lot cleaner, and it is easy to maintain in the future.

Comment: Thanks. I already implemetned Option 1 according to this example:

http://vivekcek.wordpress.com/2013/06/29/custom-form-authentication-in-mvc-4-with-custom-authorize-attribute-and-session-variable/

Now I will try to write my own Custom Membership Provider